# How to strip the leading Unciode characters from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I am processing a few thousand xml files and have a few problem files.

In each case, they contain leading Unicode characters, such as `C3 AF C2 BB C2 BF` and `EF BB BF`, etc.

In all cases, the file contains only ASCII characters (after the header bytes), so that there would be no risk of data loss converting them to ASCII.

I am not allowed to change the contents of the files on disk, only use them as input to my script.

At its simplest, I would be happy to convert such files to ASCII (all input files are parsed, some changes made and written to an output directory, where a second script will process them.)

How would I code that? When I try:

```
with open(filePath, "rb") as file:
    contentOfFile = file.read()

unicodeData = contentOfFile.decode("utf-8")
asciiData = unicodeData.encode("ascii", "ignore")

with open(filePath, 'wt')  as file:
    file.write(asciiData)
```

I get an error `must be str, not bytes`.

I also tried

```
    asciiData = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicodeData).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
```

with the same result. How do I correct that?

Or is there any other way to covert the file?

Comment: Technically, those aren't characters; They are the BOM bytes. They ideally they wouldn't appear in the input stream when reading a file as Unicode text (but I don't know how Python handles BOMs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
asciiData = unicodeData.encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

`asciiData` is bytes object because it's encoded. You need to use binary mode instead of text mode when opening file:

```
with open(filePath, 'wb')  as file:  # <---
    file.write(asciiData)
```

Comment: Oops, suddenly I am getting an exception: `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 1410: invalid start byte` :-(

Comment: ['Traceback (most recent call last):
', '  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1668, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
 ', 'xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element: line 56, column 0
 ', 
 'During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 ', 'Traceback (most recent call last):
 ', '  File "/home/mawg/PycharmProjects/msgGen/msgGen.py", line 820, in ParseInputFile

Comment: tree = ET.parse(inputFileName, parser=parser)
 ', '  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1223, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
 ', '  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 678, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
 ', '  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1670, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
 ', '  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1543, in _raiseerror
    raise err
 ', '  File "<string>", line None\n', 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 56, column 0\n']

Comment: @Mawg, It looks like a different issue. How about post a separate question?

Comment: @ffalsetru please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853761/convert-file-to-ascii-is-throwing-exceptions