# Convert file to Ascii is throwing exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

As a result of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742609/how-to-strip-the-leading-unciode-characters-from-a-file/31742694?noredirect=1#comment51595470_31742694), I have coded this:

```
def ConvertFileToAscii(args, filePath):
    try:
       # Firstly, make sure that the file is writable by all, otherwise we can't update it
        os.chmod(filePath, 0o666)

        with open(filePath, "rb") as file:
            contentOfFile = file.read()

        unicodeData = contentOfFile.decode("utf-8")
        asciiData = unicodeData.encode("ascii", "ignore")

        asciiData = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicodeData).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')

        temporaryFile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wt', delete=False)
        temporaryFileName = temporaryFile.name

        with open(temporaryFileName, 'wb')  as file:
            file.write(asciiData)

        if ((args.info) or (args.diagnostics)):
            print(filePath + ' converted to ASCII and stored in ' + temporaryFileName)


        return temporaryFileName

    #
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise

    except Exception as e:
        print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\nException while trying to convert ' + filePath + ' to ASCII')
        print(e)
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        print(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))

        if args.break_on_error:
            sys.exit('Break on error\n')
```

When I run it, I am getting exceptions like this:

```
['Traceback (most recent call last):
', '  File "/home/ker4hi/tools/xmlExpand/xmlExpand.py", line 99, in ConvertFileToAscii
    unicodeData = contentOfFile.decode("utf-8")
    ', "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 1081: invalid start byte"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I really don't care about data loss converting them to ASCII.

ox9C is   `Ü`    a U with a diacritical mark (Umlaut), I can live without it.

How can I convert such files to contain only the pure Ascii characters? Do I really need to open them as bi8nary and check every byte?

Comment: Intresting. It seems like it can't work with the 1081's byte - might want to check what's there (if 1080 is an EOF, it might be a good reason for a utf reader to expect a start byte. Also, if the conversion doesn't work properly for one of the previous bytes, it could affect this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
contentOfFile.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

The exception is from the *decode* phase, where you didn't ignore the error.

Comment: This answer is on the right track but it is wrong in so many ways ;-)  The output is unicode rather than ASCII bytes.  Also the request is to ignore "ascii" decoding errors not "utf-8" decoding errors.  In general, "replace" tends to give more intelligible output than "ignore".  And if possible, it is a better policy to try to find-out the original encoding rather than persisting with decoding using a known-to-be-incorrect codec.

Answer (score 1):

`0x00f6` is `ö` (ouml ) encoded in `ISO-8859-1`. My guess is you're using the wrong Unicode decoder.

Try : `unicodeData = contentOfFile.decode("ISO-8859-1")`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to load the whole file in memory and call `.decode()` on it. `open()` has `encoding` parameter (use `io.open()` on Python 2):

```
with open(filename, encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as file:
    ascii_char = file.read(1)
```

If you need an ascii transliteration of Unicode text; consider [`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode).

Answer (score 1):

> I really don't care about data loss converting them to ASCII.
>   ...
>   How can I convert such files to contain only the pure Ascii characters?

One way is to use the **replace** option for the `decode` method.  The advantage of *replace* over *ignore* is that you get placeholders for missing values which my help prevent a misinterpretation of the text.

**Be sure to use ASCII encoding rather than UTF-8.**  Otherwise, you may lose  adjacent ascii characters as the decoder attempts to re-sync.

Lastly, run `encode('ascii')` after the decoding step.  Otherwise, you're left with a unicode string instead of a byte string.

```
>>> string_of_unknown_encoding = 'L\u00f6wis'.encode('latin-1')
>>> now_in_unicode = string_of_unknown_encoding.decode('ascii', 'replace')
>>> back_to_bytes = now_in_unicode.replace('\ufffd', '?').encode('ascii')
>>> type(back_to_bytes)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(back_to_bytes)
b'L?wis'
```

That said, TheRightWay™ to do this is to start caring about data loss and use the correct encoding (clearly your input isn't in UTF-8 otherwise the decoding wouldn't have failed):

```
>>> string_of_known_latin1_encoding = 'L\u00f6wis'.encode('latin-1')
>>> now_in_unicode = string_of_known_latin1_encoding.decode('latin-1')
>>> back_to_bytes = now_in_unicode.encode('ascii', 'replace')
>>> type(back_to_bytes)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(back_to_bytes)
```